# iOS-App: cannot modify summary of changes when updating preceding edit (< 5')

Tags: bug, edits, ios-app, edit-summary

When editing a post a second time within 5 minutes, the two edits are going to be merged into a singe one, so the revision increases once only. This works fine for both iOS-App and web version.

However, in the online version, the field *Summary of changes* is pre-filled with the respective text of the first edit, which I assume is the desired behaviour, whereas in iOS-App, the field is empty; when submitting the edit, the text from both edits become concatenated.